# JSON.parse throws unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

JSON.parse throws an "unexpected token" error when I try to parse multiple JSON objects. I have used this approach before, but only when the array involved one row of query results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

The Error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

The JavaScript

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    var request = new ActiveXObject(microsoft.XMLHTTP);
    }
    request.open('POST', 'controllers/engineersOutput.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200 || request.status==304)) {

        var str = request.responseText;
        var data = JSON.parse(str);

        console.log(data);

        }
    }
    request.send();
```

The PHP

```
public function getEngineerDetails(){
        include "connect.php";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `engineers`";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $name = $row['name'];
            $pic =  $row['pic'];
            $insertedEngs = array( "name"=>$name, "pic"=>$pic );
            echo json_encode($insertedEngs);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your JSON string created from server is malformed because of the way you created it.

Don't construct the JSON string while inside the loop, construct and complete the array first, then finally encode:

```
public function getEngineerDetails() {

    include "connect.php";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `engineers`";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    // define a container first
    $data = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // while inside the loop
        // construct the array first
        $insertedEngs = array("name" => $row['name'], "pic" => $row['pic']);

        $data[] = $insertedEngs; // continually push 
    }

    // then encode output when done
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is returning a *sequence* of JSON-encoded objects, and that's not going to be recognizable to a JSON parser. Collect your objects into an array (in the PHP code) and then echo the whole array via `json_encode` when it's complete. Then your client will receive a JSON array.